# Displayed ticks on x-axis in Matplotlib using the bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot histogram data with pandas and matplotlib. I am using the `dataframe.plot()` function. The problem is, that this generates a graph with a lot of displayed ticks on the x-axis.
[histogram plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6wut.png)

The index of the dataframe is used as ticks.
Here is the code:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,12))

PLOT_CONFIG_HISTOGRAM={
    "subplots":True,
    "title":"cyclictest wakeup latency",
    "legend":True,
    "xlabel":"latency/us",
    "ylabel":"cycles",
    "logy":True,
    "kind":"bar",
}

my_dataframe.plot(ax=axes,**PLOT_CONFIG_HISTOGRAM)
```

Is there a way in matplotlib or pandas to reduce the displayed ticks? Or a better way to display histogram data?

In the end should be something like this:

```
| | | | |
|       |
1       5
```

or like this:

```
|       |
1       5
```

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use a fixed number, e.g. `20`, of bins for your plot:

```
PLOT_CONFIG_HISTOGRAM={
    [...]
    "bins": 20,
    [...]
}
```

Or if you want to keep the histograms resolution but want to lower the resolution of the labels of your x-axis, e.g. show only every `50`th tick:

```
div = 50
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.xticks(locs[::div], labels[::div])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. This does only affect the last graph of my plot. I guess this is because it is the "interactive way" and not the "OO way" of matplotlib? How can I do this for each axes?

Comment: Ok I did manage to do it on my own by using `get_xticks()`,`get_xticklabels()`,`set_xticks()` and `set_xticklabels()`. But I feel like, there should be an easier way to set the ticks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the number of ticks you want by specifying the number of bins in locator_params:

```
plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=10)
```

To clean up your plot further, you can also rotate the xticks and set the xlimits as below:

```
plt.xticks(rotation = '90')
plt.xlim(a,b) #where a and b represent the minimum and maximum of your x values
```